# Tracking open or closed hand with Kinect using MS SDK?

Tags: c#, kinect

I am looking for a way to detect if each hand on a person is open or closed. I tried using candescent by opening up the depth limit (it's normally at 950), but the data was not reliable at any distance farther than the limit where the Kinect has a cut-off for. It's also not possible for me to use the new kinect for the near-mode. Any ideas on how I can reliably find if a hand is open or closed?

I have searched through all existing projects that I could find and did not find any good way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but you might want to try this: [Simple Hand Tracking with MS Kinect SDK & WPF](http://kinecthandtracking.codeplex.com/)